# Is Arcgis possible for android?

Tags: android, web-services, arcgis

I want to develop Arcgis for android and web service, but I don't know it has an API yet?
If it has, it's possible to mark(like google map API) on a map which i get lat and long which collected on my server?

Thanks ka :))

Comment: Take a look: http://joesonic.com/blog/2010/07/16/arcgis-for-android-api-under-development/

Comment: @Harry Joy: link appears to be dead..

Comment: @Radek: on the day I have posted it was there but now it's dead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the ArcGIS Server javaScript API (http://help.arcgis.com/EN/webapi/javascript/arcgis/index.html) for true platform independent ArcGIS Server development.

Answer (score 5):

Esri is publishing the beta of the Android API in late January 2011, the final release is scheduled for late March.
There is already some documentation on this on Esri's website:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgismobile/10.0/apis/android/help/index.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a runtime for Android you want may want to use.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/communities/runtime-android/

Cheers
Al